# Implement using in c# without show dialogue win forms

Tags: c#, forms, show, using, showdialog

I am developing a winforms application with the code below to open new form :

```
 using (Form1 f = new Form1(textBoxJobCardNo.Text, tf, tfh))
                    {
                       // System.GC.Collect();
                        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                        f.Left = sc[1].Bounds.Left;
                        f.Top = sc[1].Bounds.Top;
                        f.Height = sc[1].Bounds.Height;
                        f.Width = sc[1].Bounds.Width;
                        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
                        labelerror.Visible = false;
                        textBoxJobCardNo.Clear();
                        f.ShowDialog();


                    }
```

I am using `ShowDialog()` to open new form. In place of `ShowDialog()` I want to use `Show()` without removing using statement because the using statement helps me to free memory after form close. If I use `Show()` then it will not hold on after `Show()` and moves out of using scope, which will close the form.

When i am using `using` my ram usage is constant when i am trying to do it with show without `using` it increase 2 mb on every form open.

Can't i hold control in using like show dialog with show.

Comment: i want to know why negative vote.

Comment: Why do you need to use 'Show()' when your actual requirement is to implement the behavior of 'ShowDialog()'?

Comment: because i am using multiple monitor scenario in which if user click on secondary screen primary screen loss focus but in case of show it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't show the form modally (using `ShowDialog()`), by default, it'll be disposed on closing. This is what [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your application, your application ends.
>
> The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

So there's no need to call `Dispose()` (or use a `using` block) if the form is not modal and not MDI, it'll be freed when closed.

That said, this is an implementation detail that might change (although at this point in time, it's unlikely that it will), and it should be safe to call `Dispose()` multiple times if you want.

Comment: @jcl my application is neither mdi and i am not using ShowDialog also still it increase ram 2 mb every time i open new form and not releasing  on form close(). As every one said it will be released on when garbage collection but  i tried it for long time till application consumes 200 mb.

Comment: The GC will collect the memory when it sees fit. And if it never does, it's because you are keeping references to the object somewhere, in that case, neither Dispose()  nor Collect() will help

Comment: Having 200mb of memory is not a reason for the GC to force a memory collect, if the system has free resources. The folks at Microsoft who wrote the GC are extremely talented and probably know more than you and me about memory management. Let them do the work for you. You only need to take care of not having references to objects in your code when they are not needed any more

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code in the FormClosed Eventhandler of the form

```
  this.Dispose();
```

aka:

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

The using block does nothing more than call dispose() on the resource you specify after the block ended. If you handle Disposing your Resources yourself you dont have to use the using block and your Resources are freed the way you specify, in this example after the Form has been closed.

Edit:

```
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure, how this is relevant to the actual question?

Comment: @Thangadurai It's somewhat relevant, because OP says they want to "help to free memory after form close".

Comment: @Thangadurai not only it's relevant. It's an actual good answer (save a few caveats, but it's probably ok for the OP)

Comment: About the caveats, disposing on an event is not the right thing to do, since others could be subscribing to that event afterwards and the object would be disposed already... I'd rather derive from `Form` and override `OnClosed` to make sure all subscribed delegates are called before disposing. I've upvoted nonetheless, but the caveat should be specified in the answer

Comment: @J.Steen, Yes. Agree with it.

Comment: Actually, now that I've checked, I was wrong, this is not the right answer actually

Comment: That would apply if other objects subscribe to the formclosed event?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger yes, if your event handler gets called before other subscribed delegates, you'll have disposed the form before the other delegates get called. This, however, is not needed. See my answer

Comment: this.dispose() is not releasing memory.

Comment: @HotCoolStud `Dispose()` does not free up memory. The memory is freed by the garbage collector when not needed. `Dispose()` only releases unmanaged resources and having an object "disposed" is just a pattern: there's nothing special about a `Dispose()` function that makes the GC free the associated memory

Comment: The line you had allready :'System.GC.Collect()' does the actual freeing of the memory however its in most cases a bad idea to start it manually. .NetFx does this on its own when needed.

Comment: Not even... `GC.Collect()` only -hints- the garbage collector that it should collect memory, but it's not even guaranteed to do it. About when to call `GC.Collect()`? Short answer: **never** (long answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Form.Show()` should be called without a `using` block because it will return immediately after showing the form, so that the user can access the new form and all other forms that are present. In a `using` block the newly shown form would be destroyed immediately after creation because of the automatic `Dispose()` call at the end of the block.

`Form.ShowDialog()` returns much later: after the Modal form is closed, so this will work fine in a `using` block.